Organizing Django Project: Separating App into Multiple Servers with Shared Database and User Model
In our project, we plan to split one Django app from the monolith into a separate server, while using a single database for both. I don't understand how to correctly utilize the user model, which will be shared between the two servers. Should migrations, both existing and future ones, remain in one repository or should they be split between the two?
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)


    email = models.EmailField(_("Email address"), unique=True)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True


Explored various architectural options for splitting a Django app into two servers with a shared database. Reviewed Django documentation regarding the use of a shared user model. Expecting to find an optimal way to utilize the user model in this scenario and ensure migration synchronization for both servers
